# Align rotated div with another div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a main div (the red div in the fiddle) that has a smaller vertical tab on the side (the blue div in the fiddle).

The RED div is standard BUT the Blue div is rotated through 90 degrees (as I need to have vertical text in it). This is where the problems starts.

The red div is vertically positioned at 50% so it is in the middle of the page and locked with scrolling etc.

I want to align the blue div so that the top edge of the blue div is at the same Y position as the top edge of the red div.

I would prefer NOT to use jQuery but can do if required.

Desired output :

[image]

Fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/kBKf6/

Here is the code I am using :

```
<div id="main" style="position: fixed; top: 50%;  margin-top: -250px; left:0;   height: 500px; width: 450px; background-color:red;">
Main Content Div
</div>
<div id="vertical_div" style="overflow:hidden; position: fixed; left:350px; height:40px; width:200px; margin: auto; background-color:blue; text-align:center; color:white; -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%); -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%); transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);">
Side Tab
</div>
```

Comment: please avoid inline styles

Comment: CSS extracted to stylesheet - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/kBKf6/3/

Comment: "I want to align (using JS) the blue div so that the top edge of the blue div is at the same Y position as the top edge of the red div." well isn't it already aligned...?  BTW you might want to read this - [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: looks like its aligned

Comment: looks like this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/kBKf6/19/ or this one http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/kBKf6/24/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need JS to align the rotated div. You can define a [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) in CSS  then, it becomes easy to align.

- Side note : You can remove the `-moz-` and `-o-` vendor prefixes see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kBKf6/35/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="main">Main Content Div
    <div id="verticaldiv">Side Tab</div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    left:0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color:red;
}

#verticaldiv {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    bottom:100%;
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:0 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer IMO + 1

Comment: That is a fantastic solution - Thank you :)

How would I modify it please so that the red div can lock to the right hand edge of the page (using right:0;) and the blue div sticks out from the left hand edge of the right div (if you get what I mean)

Comment: Good answer ! Just change top: -40px; by bottom: 100%; to get rid of size dependencies

Comment: Yes - that's perfect web-tiki - Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without relying on hardcoded sizes that move your div into position, but you need a wrapper around your `.verticaldiv`

demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MCr6f/

demo 2: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9LtKw/ (to show that different sizes don't matter)

html:

```
<div class="one">
    Hello
    <div class="pivot">
        <div class="two">
            Pretty!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.one {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

     /*strange and difficult sizes*/
    font-size: 3.237827em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.pivot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.two {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    /*strange and difficult sizes*/
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
```